# How can I scroll to a particular element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dropdown, webflow

context: webflow has a built in dropdown and when it's open it has a class of "w--open". Here I'm giving my button with the class name "hover-close" the ability to close that dropdown by removing the "w--open".

It works but when it closes it scrolls all the way to the top of the page instead of to the dropdown element with the class "dropdown-list-9 w-dropdown-list".

````
  (function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(".hover-close").on("click", function () {
      $(".dropdown-list-9.w-dropdown-list").removeClass(" w--open");
      $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
      $(".dropdown-list-9 w-dropdown-list").not($(this).next()).slideUp("fast");
      //Scroll to top for each accordion that is clicked.
      // The "180" is the distance from top. The "300" is the scroll speed. The "400" is for the animation delay depending on inner content length.
      setTimeout(() => {
        $('html').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top-3000}, 300);
      }, 400);
    });
  }(jQuery));
</script>```
````

Comment: Can you show your html code? Maybe you are using `<a href="#"></a>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `<a>` element and set property to this tag and perform click on this tag run time.

```js
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = '#sectionId';
    document.body.append(a);
    a.click();
    a.remove();
```

```html
<p>on load this page will scroll to the section</p>
<pre>
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
</pre>
<section id="sectionId">
Section
</section>
```